# Quotes in strings with Process.Start in C#, Mono 3.5 (Unity), OSX

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, mono

Searching stackoverflow and Google this question has only been answered in the context of Windows and .NET not the Mono version used in Unity3D on OSX. For whatever reason none of the solutions or answers I've found have worked on in Unity3D's Mono on OSX. It's possible I'm doing something incredibly stupid OR it's possible something is fundamentally broke on Unity3D's Mono+OSX. Hence this question

I'm trying to execute a simple command using C#, Mono(Unity3D), OSX. To keep it simple here's the command from the shell

```
/bin/sh -c "echo \"hello world\""
```

That works. Here's my C# code

```
// original working line
// /bin/sh      -c "echo \"hello world\""
string args = @"-c ""echo \""hello world\""""";

var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "/bin/sh",
        Arguments = args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    },
};
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
result += proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
Debug.Log(proc.ExitCode);
Debug.Log(result);
```

It fails with

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/bin/sh', CommandLine='-c "echo \"hello world\""', CurrentDirectory=''
```

You can see the arguments (ie, `CommandLine=`) seem to be correct

Removing the inner quotes works

```
string args = @"-c ""echo hello world""";
```

but of course I ultimately need the quotes for my actual use case.

How do I pass quotes to `Process.Start` on Mono(Unity3D) OSX?

## Update

It turns out this is some kind of issue specifically with Mono in Unity3D. If run the same code in Xamarin Studio it works as expected.

Still looking for a possible workaround.

Comment: with my reputation being 21k plus maybe you'd give me the benefit of the doubt that I've been working on this for 6 hours now. Mono+OSX+C# is not well covered where as .NET on Window is.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on centos by the way. It's surprising it's any different on OSX.

Comment: See above. It's apparently an issue with the mono used in Unity. Works fine in Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 0):

the [ " ] sign informs about start or end string, for this to be treated as a simple sign you need to use [ \ ] character whenever you need to plase quotes, or use unicode/ascii code.

Your example:

```
// -c "echo \"hello world\""
string args = "-c \"echo \"hello world\"\"";
```

To be able to read from the IO stream you need to be sure that the process started correctly. 
You can do this simply by :

```
proc.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Then You should be able to read from it's IO.

Comment: Thank but your example isn't making any sense. See the syntax highlighting. The `@` sign means a single quote ends the string and backslash is just a literal backslash which means your line isn't valid C#.

I'm not sure what you're trying to get me to do. If you want me to pass backslashes for every quote all the way to the process it would be `@"-c \""echo \""hello world\""\""";` but that makes no sense. Do you really want the first and last quotes to have slashes? That's not what you showed in comment. Maybe you meant `@"-c ""echo \""hello world\""""";` but that's exactly what I had.

Comment: Sorry, my bad didn't notice  '@' sign when copied. But still when You remove '@' from the beginning and wait for the input this SHOULD work (at least worked for me) :)

Comment: Even without the at sign it makes no sense. Your string un-escaped is `-c "echo "hello world""`. If you wanted to pass `-c "echo \"hello world\""` then you'd need `string args = "-c \"echo \\\"hello world\\\"\"";`. Also does it work in Unity3D's Mono? (since that's the question) As pointed out above my original example works in normal mono. It's only Unity's mono where it's failing.

Comment: It is not Unity's Mono, just simple Mono. And yes, this works with Mono but Unity has it's own restrictions so i recommend to read those:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/820611/how-to-access-net-application-from-unity-via-a-pro.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx